# Node-config custom-environment-variables not overridding default.json during test

Tags: node.js, node-config

Node-config's custom-environment-variables.json doesn't seem to be overriding values in default.json when NODE_ENV is set to 'test.' Here's an extremely simple config:

config/default.json:

```
{
  "jwtPrivateKey": "defaultkey"
}
```

config/custom-environment-variables.json:

```
{
 "jwtPrivateKey": "JWTPRIVATEKEY"
}
```

config/test.json:

```
{}
```

app.js:

```
console.log('NODE_ENV': + process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log('Env: ' + process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY);
console.log("Config: " + config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
```

This works as expected: I get NODE_ENV=undefined (so node-config will default to 'development'), & the next two lines both print the correct value set in the environment variable.  However, if I try to run a simple test with Jest & print the same:

tests/some.test.js:

```
test('Some Test', () => {
    console.log('NODE_ENV:' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
    console.log('Env: ' + process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY);
    console.log("Config: " + config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));
});
```

I get NODE_ENV=test, Env=the correct value set in the environment variable...but Config=defaultKey.

In other words: although it shows that the environment variable is set to the right value, node-config doesn't seem to be pulling it in through custom-environment-variables.json.

Is this a bug?  I've scoured the documentation but been unable to find any reason for this discrepancy.

Answer (score 5):

Do you by chance have a `local.json` file in your config folder? If so, this is a special file type that overrides everything, so your values may match this config's values exactly. The `NODE_ENV` var seemingly doesn't affect whether or not `local.json` is loaded last.

I just ran into this issue and temporarily renaming/removing the `local.json` solved my problem.

Comment: Nope, no local.config.  Thanks for the idea tho :)

Comment: Dang! Feel free to check the load order to make sure the your files match the load order: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#file-load-order. It feels like to me the contents of `config/custom-environment-variables.json` should actually be in `test.json`. Edit: Never mind, I read the docs and understand what you're trying to do. I will report back if I find anything.

Comment: I've spent the last 24 hours completely stumped and this answer solved my issues. I had made a local config to separate from the development config to be used on the dev server. Thanks you so much!!!! Almost 4 years later!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You must set env value before config module load

```
process.env.TargetEnv=1234 // <=== override default value
import config from 'config'
```

```
import config from 'config'
process.env.TargetEnv=1234 // <=== not override default value
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it.

require('dotenv').config();
import config from 'config';

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused about this and search all different platforms and finally got this link from the reported issue of node-config.

[image]

[dont use local](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/255)

Comment: Is this different from the answer adrum gave in May 2019...?